# Python sqlite3 operational error when string formatting?

Tags: python, sqlite, string-formatting

I have this small decorator function where I am going to find an unknown number of entries in a table:

```
def Deco(func):
     func
     conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/User/vocab_database/vocab.db')
     with conn:
         cur = conn.cursor()
         cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
         total = cur.fetchall()
         print "You have %d tables " % len(total)

       ## this line below, is where I wanted to use a formatted string ##
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s") % total[0]
         entries = cur.fetchall()
         print "You have %d entries" % len(entries)
```

Then I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./database_trial.py", line 19, in <module>
    class Vocab:
  File "./database_trial.py", line 25, in Vocab
    @Deco        
  File "./database_trial.py", line 15, in Deco
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s") % total[0]
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Does sqlite3 only accept `?` operators?  Or is there something I'm mucking up?

Comment: That's not string interpolation.

Comment: Another name for using the mod operator on strings. And harder to confuse with the `format()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to replace metadata, so unfortunately a parametrized query won't work. You must use interpolation or the like here, but **make sure that the value is sanitized; this is a possible vector for a SQL injection**.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (total[0],))
```

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (total[0],))` returns error `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s" % (total[0],))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error`

Comment: Then you have a problem in `total[0]`.

Comment: I just had print out `total[0] = (u'Words',)` so I would have to use `total[0][0]`. To be clear though the `?` wouldn't work in this case either way?  Much Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Any field names, table names, etc ?

Answer (score 2):

In the line `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM %s") % total[0]`, you are applying the `%` operator to the result of the `cur.execute` call.  I think you want to do the substitution inside the call, e.g., `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", (total[0],))`.

Comment: You omitted the comma.  It's `(total[0],)`, not `(total[0])`.

Comment: `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", (total[0],))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error` even with the comma.